# R ggplot histogram with 2 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a histogram in ggplot. It's a basic one on the Titanic Dataset in kaggle. Im trying to see count of age in histogram by age group, and the histogram to display also survived class which contains 0 or 1 .
Unfortunately is showing all dataset, not each splited by Survived (0 or 1)

Sample desired output is in the image below. I think it's a pretty simple issue, just I am new to ggplot.
dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic

```
ggplot(titanic, aes(x=Age, fill= Survived))+
  geom_histogram(color="darkblue", fill="lightblue",)
```

[image]

Comment: `fill = "lightblue"` overrides the `fill = Survived`. Remove the `fill = "lightblue"`, and if you want custom colors use `scale_fill_manual()`. (e.g., `.... + scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightblue", "firebrick2"))`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this. The advice from **@GregorThomas** is great. Just be careful on setting the `Survived` variable as factor:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
ggplot(titanic, aes(x=Age, fill= factor(Survived)),group=factor(Survived))+
  geom_histogram(color='black',binwidth = 5)+
  stat_bin(binwidth=5, geom="text", aes(label=..count..),
           position = position_stack(0.5),size=3,fontface='bold')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The exact same data is available in the `titanic` package, so in case people don't want to download data from a third-party site, the following is a full reprex:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(titanic::titanic_train, aes(x = Age, fill = factor(Survived))) +
  geom_histogram(color = "darkblue") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ed1c23", "lightblue"), name = "Survived")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>